# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, installed Unity (7.5) from Universe, how to switch to Unity 7.6? (if advisable)

Tags: unity, 22.04

I've heard that great upgrades came with the latest release Unity 7.6.
I am using Unity since all the years, simply by having it installed from the Universe repo on the default Ubuntu (Gnome desktop) distribution.

But that up to day still has version 7.5.1 – how could I update to 7.6 or is it better to wait?

Comment: You have two supported choices: 1) Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Unity 7.5. 2) Ubuntu non-LTS 23.04 with Unity 7.7.  Which of those choices is "better" is up to you. Both are better than any unsupported option, including trying to bolt a different release of Unity onto an LTS.

Comment: *"is it better to wait?"* - This is a question you need to answer for yourself. You'll need to ask yourself how badly do you need the new features. Then ask if that's worth the risks of using unsupported software (bugs, crashes, dependency problems, etc) Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283)

Answer (score 2):

> I've heard that great upgrades came with the latest release Unity 7.6

The latest stable version of Unity is 7.7 (as of December 2022).

---

> But that up to day still has version 7.5.1 – how could I update to 7.6 or is it better to wait?

There are [reasons](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/124466) why Ubuntu repositories do not have the latest versions of all packages. **Ubuntu 22.04 will never receive the Unity 7.6 update.**

A quick search in [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unity) shows that Ubuntu 22.04 has Unity 7.5.1, Ubuntu 22.10 has Unity 7.6, and Ubuntu 23.04 comes with Unity 7.7.

So, if you want to use the latest version of Unity, try [Ubuntu Unity Remix](https://ubuntuunity.org/), which is an official flavor of Ubuntu beyond version 22.10. Version 22.10 will lose support in a few months, so I would suggest you to try the most recent version, 23.04. However, 23.04 is **not** an LTS version, and will be only supported till Januar